# how do i set json data set as labels for graph plot with c3.js

Tags: javascript, json, c3.js

I have a line graph generated with c3.js with json data

the current chart is very simple

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '.balanceChart',
  data: {
    url: '/data',
    mimeType:'json'
  }
});
```

json data:

```
{
  data1: [1000,1240,1270,1250,1280]
  data2: [1000,240,30,-20,30]
}
```

chart looks good and is there
but it is currently plotting both sets of data
what i would like is for data2 to be the tooltip value of the plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide data2 from displaying like so

```
data: {
  ...
  hide: ['data2']
}
```

From http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-hide

And use tooltip.format.value to change the tooltip display

```
tooltip: {
  format: {
    value: function (value, ratio, id, index) { 
          // return chart.data.values("data2")[index]; // if still wanting to use data2

          // or get rid of data2 completely using this
          var vals = chart.data.values(id); // id will be 'data1', vals will then be data1 array
          return vals[index] - (index === 0 ? 0 : vals[index - 1]);
      }
  }
}
```

http://c3js.org/reference.html#tooltip-format-value

tooltip.format.title and tooltip.format.name will also be useful here to communicate to  a user the value isn't actually that of data1 (maybe just changing the title to "Delta Data1")

Comment: well i dont get any errors but i also have no tooltips

Comment: oops  hit enter for a new line    since i started using a url to get my json data i have no tooltips showing up at all  any ideas?

Comment: my bad i had my chart inside a span instead of a div for some reason  thank you very much for the help it is working perfectly    much appreciated